# webform_submission_ID post blocked by CAPTCHA module

Tags: webforms, captcha

After solving reCAPTCHA and submitting the form I am getting error:
*The answer you entered for the CAPTCHA was not correct.*

Recent log message says:

```
webform_submission_ID post blocked by CAPTCHA module: challenge reCAPTCHA (by module recaptcha), user answered "Google no captcha", but the solution was "1".
```

I couldn't find any working solution. I already tried to update reCAPTCHA and Captcha modules to newer version. Also tried to update Drupal core.

Any suggestions?

I am using Drupal core 8.5.8 and reCaptcha 8.x-2.3

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Debugging always needs to be done by you. It could be anything. Server side caching, JS errors, custom code, your browser, anything. That unfortunately makes it too broad to be answered in a Q&A format without lots of forum-like back and forth clarification in the comments.

Comment: I upvoted this question because I had this problem as well, and even though my solution wasn't the same, I don't think the error message is obvious or helpful and I ended up googling for a solution.  I don't think the question is bad (it was at -2 when I got here....)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. Webform configuration files were imported after the Webform module has been updated and it caused the older configuration to be out-of-sync. As a result unexpected behaviors and errors were showing.

Clicking the 'Repair Configuration' button under '/admin/structure/webform/config/advanced' helped.